# Can't dynamically render reactjs elements using .map()

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically render out ingredient/qty/measure using `.map()` in `reactjs` I am following a few tutorials online but unable to properly implement the code in my own code.

Here is the error I am currently getting:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. 
This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. 
Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Here is the data I am trying to `map` over:

```
recipeIngredients: Array(2)
0: {name: 'lemon', quantity: '100', measure: 'g'}
1: {name: 'butter', quantity: '5', measure: 'cups'}
```

Here is my code:

```
import './IngredientsList.css'

let ingredientArray
function mapIngredients() {
  ingredientArray.map((item) => (
    <div className="ingredient-element">{item}</div>
  ))
}

function IngredientsList(props) {
  console.log(props)
  ingredientArray = props.recipeIngredients

  return <div className="ingredient-list">{mapIngredients}</div>
}

export default IngredientsList
```

Basically, trying to render out the following set of divs (`recipeIngredients.name` has an additional class):

```
<div className="ingredient-list">
    <div className="ingredient-element">recipeIngredients.quantity</div>
    <div className="ingredient-element">recipeIngredients.measure</div>
    <div className="ingredient-element ingredient-name">recipeIngredients.name</div>
  </div>
```

I notice that the () are missing from the `IngredientList` function - VSCode keeps deleting them when I save the code so I can't manually add them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to invoke the function.  Here you're trying to render the function itself:

```
return <div className="ingredient-list">{mapIngredients}</div>
```

Instead, invoke the function and render its result:

```
return <div className="ingredient-list">{mapIngredients()}</div>
```

Additionally, the function currently doesn't *return* anything.  Add a `return` statement:

```
function mapIngredients() {
  return ingredientArray.map((item) => (
    <div className="ingredient-element">{item}</div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now the error I get is: ``Uncaught TypeError: ingredientArray.map is not a function``

Comment: @deadant88: That suggests that `ingredientArray` is not an array.  So what is it?  You can log it to the console to see what it is.

Comment: Yes it is an object, I jst had to chnage ``{item}`` to ``{item.name}}`` etc. Thanks for the help! One last thing, if possible: how do I render a unique key for each item? What I am trying (just making key ``item.name`` etc is resulting in ``Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.``

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two issues here. First, you're not invoking the function(as you said that vs code is not letting you do that). The second is `item` is an object here. Try this instead:-

```
function IngredientsList(props) {
  console.log(props)
  ingredientArray = props.recipeIngredients || [];

  return (
    <div className="ingredient-list">
      {
        ingredientArray.map(item => (
          <div className="ingredient-element">{item.name}</div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```